# Update gradle error i have a problem when im add library and update that

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Build file '/home/yan/AndroidStudioProjects/JobScheduler/app/build.gradle' line: 8

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_40adk7t6kzk2mbl6murbw9xfd.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_40adk7t6kzk2mbl6murbw9xfd$_run_closure1) values: [build_40adk7t6kzk2mbl6murbw9xfd$_run_closure1@434df441]
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Bag.png)